# copy the tkinter filedialog.py to my code in order to debug

Tags: python, tkinter, module

I want to debug the code in [file-explorer-in-python-using-tkinter (link1 code)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-explorer-in-python-using-tkinter/)  specially the part that exists in `from tkinter import filedialog` but the IDEs don't go over to another file while debugging tkinter (maybe this could be solved but right now is not the concern) so I want to copy the code in the `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\tkinter\filedialog.py`, to the beginning of my code (`link1`) and comment the line `# from tkinter import filedialog` in the code of `link1` but I get error `NameError: name 'filedialog' is not defined` and I tried some other things like changing `filedialog` to `FileDialog()` in this part of `link1` code

```
def browseFiles():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",
                                          title = "Select a File",
                                          filetypes = (("Text files",
                                                        "*.txt*"),
                                                       ("all files",
                                                        "*.*")))
```

but didn't work also.

So my question is what changes should I do to `link1` code in order to run the code in one file, while the beginning is the copy of `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\tkinter\filedialog.py` and the rest is `link1` code?

Comment: What IDE are you using? While it may not work to debug imported libraries from you python installation, you should can try to copy the entire file `filedialog.py` next to your `link1.py` and add debug stops in there. Then you only have to `import filedialog` at the beginning of your `link1.py`

Comment: Im using 'spyder', and ur suggestion resulted `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'filedialog'`

Comment: Sounds like your IDE does not make the directory the script being run the current working directory. You may be able to work around it by prepending the folder `'.'` to `sys.path` at near the beginning of the code.

Comment: try `filename = filedialog.askopenfilename` to `filename = askopenfilename`

Comment: @martineau I don't think thats the case, it sounds u are suggest copying 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\tkinter\filedialog.py' to directory the my link1 code exists but again in another folder? did I catch u right?

Comment: No — copy `filedialog.py` to the same folder that your link1 code is in.

Comment: @martineau so again its in another file, the IDE can't go to another file while debugging, no matter the folder

Comment: I find that hard to believe — and think you must be mistaken.

Comment: @martineau thanks anyway, I'll try it

Comment: `spyder` can step into `filedialog.py` file in tkinter folder when in debugging mode.

Comment: @acw1668 actually have realized that 'continue until next breakpoint' doesn't work but it can 'step into'!!!